# How to put text in front of auto increment field in mysql (like : TTT00001)?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to put some text in front of my auto increment field with mysql, 
but I still have no answer to do this.
here is the example data that I want to insert into table

"IDC00000001"

and what I do now just auto incremented integer with zerofill format,
and the result just 00000001.

and I want the number auto incremented. so when Insert some data again it will be like this
"IDC00000002", "IDC00000003",........,"IDC00000022",etc

my questions:

1. how to solved this case?
2. am I need a store procedure?
3. what is best practice to do this, prepare this in php before insert or in mysql directly?

Comment: The first question you need to ask is "WHY" do you need this? Why not just use the auto-increment number, and add "ID" in front of it when fetching the data?

Comment: You're using PHP, just stick your prefix in during serialization, when you turn your SQL results into "whatever" (but most likely, HTML). The whole point of an autoincrementing `id` is that it's a guaranteed, unique-per-new-record number, don't try to change that: just add your string only at the point where that string becomes *needed*.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie I want to display user id in front end same with id in database to make easier when we want to query. Thanks junkfoodjunkie

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thank you for your advice, Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is trigger and one more table. Try this trigger below;

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER tg_tableName_insert
BEFORE INSERT ON tableName
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tableName_seq VALUES (NULL);
  SET NEW.id = CONCAT('IDC', LPAD(LAST_INSERT_ID(), 8, '0'));
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Dont forget to create sequence table;

```
CREATE TABLE tableName_seq
(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE tableName
(
  id VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT '0'
);
```

When you insert data to the tableName table your first id will be IDC00000001 and second IDC00000002 goes like that. I hope it helps!

Comment: Why make things this complicated? They're in PHP, all they need to do is prepend a constant string to the `id` field during serialization.

Comment: They asked "what is best practice to do this? From my perspective it is the best practice to do that mate. It is not complicated, I just wrote a trigger thats all.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for your advice

Comment: @MuratGüner It's work. Thank you very much. Murat